# Model can't see has_many relation, getting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, models

I'm having trouble with association in rails' model.

I got such piece of code

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rooms
  has_many :tokens, dependent: :destroy

  has_secure_password
  //[...] - some validations not according to my model
```

Then in my controller I have

```
def create
  unique_id = SecureRandom.uuid
  @room = @current_member.rooms.new(unique_id: unique_id)
  @room_details = RoomDetail.new(video_url: 'test', room: @room)

  if @room.save
    render json: @room, status: :created, location: @room
  else
    render json: @room.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Recently everything worked as it should. Now, after creating tokens table + adding that to models it says

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `rooms' for #<Member::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00560114fbf1d8>>",
```

I'm getting user with this method.

```
def authenticate_token
  authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
    @current_member = Member.joins(:tokens).where(:tokens => { :token => token })
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will need to change to get an instance (not a relation).  Just add `first` to the end.

```
authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
    @current_member = Member.joins(:tokens).where(:tokens => { :token => token }).first
end
```

Note, the error is on the `ActiveRecord_Relation` object.

Also, not sure how you are debugging, but I recommend using https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors to see the error at the time and inspect the objects.  Would have been an easy catch here.

Comment: Great, it works like charm! I've been trying something with ```first``` but definitely not there :D Thank you! EDIT: Im using RubyMine as I'm used to IntelliJ IDEA in Java